# when i add category it give me this "Secondary Description" attribute value is empty"

Tags: magento-2.1, category, category-attribute

Suddenly Magento starts giving this error ... I tried to **`var_dump()`** what is missing, also check the file but there is no problem with it.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error would suggest you've created a category attribute called Seconday Description and it is set as required.

Have you created this attribute?

Check the eav tables in db.

As how to solve. Depends. Do you want and use this attribute? You could delete it?

Comment: Solved: yeah i created EAV attribute, and I it's value to be is_required =1.
i changed it's requirement to zero now everything is working fine

Comment: @IzharMehdi that's good news. Feel free to mark the answer as the accepted solution :)

Comment: my reputation is less then 15 :D

Comment: @IzharMehdi check again.  Welcome to the community.